# Google Play not automatically updated

Tags: android, google-play, auto-update

I prepared my own I published in android apps on Google Play. Downloading app. However, I publish every new device is installed after the application version is not automatically updated. I tried on all devices. I activated the automatic update option from the Google Play app.

Unfortunately, I get the same results. Is there that might help?

Answer (score -1):

Solution.
Add validation code inside your own app to check application version and open Google Play if newer is released. You can store version somewhere in your own server.

Automatic application updates are not popular in Android devices. Sad but true.

Do not forget whether your enabled this option in your device https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113412?hl=en